# Meaning of $[\mathbb K : \mathbb Q]$

Tags: notation, field-theory, definition, extension-field

What is the meaning of $[\mathbb K : \mathbb Q]$ where $\mathbb K$ and $\mathbb Q$ are fields. This is galois theory, abstract algebra.

What does this actually mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means the dimension of $\mathbb{K}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. It is called the degree of the extension.

If $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, for an algebraic $\alpha$, then the degree of the extension is the degree of the minimal polynomial. Indeed, then  $\alpha^{i}$ for $i = 0, \dots,  [\mathbb K : \mathbb Q]-1$ is a basis for  $\mathbb K$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: OK so how does the degree of the extension relate to minimum polynomials?

Comment: I added the information.

Comment: For the basis part, we have seen a theorem that states what you said basically but what if we had $\mathbb Q (\alpha, \beta)$ with both alpha and beta being algebraic? So what if I wanted to find a basis of $\mathbb (\sqrt2 , \sqrt3 ) $ over $\mathbb Q $?

Comment: In that case you can apply the argument twice, and use that the degree is multiplicative. Or, find one element that generate the same field. But the problem is not always easy. I see you got answers to this on another post, so I will not elaborate further for now. But do not hesitate to ask

Comment: so we have the set $\{ 1, \sqrt2 , \sqrt3, \sqrt6 \}$ which might be a basis. We know from theorems in linear algebra that if we have that the number of elements equals the dimension (which it does in our case), we only have to check linear independence OR if it spans the whole set - we don't need to check both. But I don't know how either of them are proved...

Comment: I think I see how it spans the whole set. We need to prove that $\{a \cdot 1+ b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3 +d\sqrt6 : a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Q\} = \mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$ but we know that elements of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$ are written as $a +b\sqrt2 +c\sqrt3+d\sqrt6 $ so we can clearly see that these two sets are equal. Hence it spans the set. And since the dimension number is equal to the number of elements in our so called basis, it must be a basis of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$. Is this valid?

Comment: But say if we were not allowed to use the theorem concerning the dimension and cardinality of the 'basis' being equal, how would we prove linear independence??? Seems impossible.

Comment: All arguments ultimately boil down to showing/knowing $\sqrt{3}$ not being in $Q(\sqrt{2})$ that is it is not of the form $a+b \sqrt{2}$ for rational $a,b$. (At least if you take for granted that $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are not rational.) You cannot get the argument cheaper than this.

Comment: @quid, I would appreciate if you could take a look at the closure at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648838/is-it-to-the-students-advantage-to-learn-the-language-of-infinitesimals

Comment: @user72694 I voted to reopen. As a general matter of following procedures I'd prefer though to receive such comments in chat. But perhaps I am bit too fuzzy with that.

Comment: @quid, I am not sure how to use chat. Perhaps you could provide an email address?

Comment: @user72694 in the topbar where there is the list of sites there it is written chat. Follow the link than chose a room. A low volume room where you can notify me is http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10243/mo-editors-lounge (its attached to MO though but this is not very substantive) Nofify works as on the sites; it is no problem if the other person is not online. (Sorry, as a rule, I prefer not to do email correspondence related to SE sites.)